# Magento2: Template how to edit header

Tags: magento2, template, design

I want little change header in template.

- 1) I need to shorten a little search engine
- 2) Move logo to banner search engine
- 3) Search engine move to up and stick always on top.

[image]

Can anyone help me from what should I start?

Edit:
file logo.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo $block
 */
?>
<?php $storeName = $block->getThemeName() ? $block->getThemeName() : $block->getLogoAlt(); ?>
<div class="logo-wrapper">
    <h1 class="logo-content">
        <strong class="logo">
            <a class="logo" href="<?php echo $block->getUrl(''); ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo $storeName ?>">
                <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo $block->getLogoSrc() ?>"
                     alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                     echo $block->getLogoAlt() ?>"
                    <?php echo $block->getLogoWidth() ? 'width="' . $block->getLogoWidth() . '"' : '' ?>
                    <?php echo $block->getLogoHeight() ? 'height="' . $block->getLogoHeight() . '"' : '' ?>
                />

            </a>
        </strong>
    </h1>
</div>
```

searchbox.form.mini.phtml

```
<?php

/**------------------------------------------------------------------------

 * SM Search Box - Version 2.0.0

 * Copyright (c) 2015 YouTech Company. All Rights Reserved.

 * @license - Copyrighted Commercial Software

 * Author: YouTech Company

 * Websites: http://www.magentech.com

 * -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/



if (!$this->_getConfig('isenabled', 1)) return;



/** @var $block \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template */

/** @var $helper \Sm\SearchBox\Helper\Data */

/** @var $helperSearch \Magento\Search\Helper\Data */



$helperSearch = $this->helper('Magento\Search\Helper\Data');

$helper       = $this->helper('Sm\SearchBox\Helper\Data');

$tag_id       = 'sm_searchbox' . rand() . time();

$cat_list     = $this->getCategories();



$show_popular  = $this->_getConfig('show_popular');

$limit_popular = $this->_getConfig('limit_popular');



$show_advanced = $this->_getConfig('show_advanced');

$pretext       = $this->_getConfig('pretext');

$posttext      = $this->_getConfig('posttext');



$show_more = $this->_getConfig('show_more');

$more_text = $this->_getConfig('more_text', 'More++');

?>



<div id="<?php echo $tag_id; ?>" class="sm-searchbox">

        <?php

        if (!empty($pretext)) { ?>

            <div class="pre-text"><?php echo $pretext; ?></div>

        <?php } ?>





    <div class="sm-searchbox-content">

            <form class="form minisearch" id="searchbox_mini_form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */

            echo $helperSearch->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">

                <div class="field searchbox">

                    <div class="control">

                        <select class="cat searchbox-cat" name="cat">

                            <option value=""><?php echo __('All Categories') ?></option>

                            <?php foreach ($cat_list as $cat) { ?>

                                <option value="<?php echo $cat['value']; ?>" <?php echo(($this->getRequest()->getParam('cat') && ($this->getRequest()->getParam('cat') == $cat['value'])) ? "selected" : ''); ?> ><?php echo $cat['label']; ?></option>

                            <?php } ?>

                        </select>



                        <input id="searchbox"

                               data-mage-init='{"quickSearch":{

                                    "formSelector":"#searchbox_mini_form",

                                    "url":"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */

                               echo $block->getUrl('search/ajax/suggest'); ?>",

                                    "destinationSelector":"#searchbox_autocomplete"}

                               }'

                               type="text"

                               name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */

                               echo $helperSearch->getQueryParamName() ?>"

                               placeholder="<?php echo __('Enter keywords to search...') ?>"

                               class="input-text input-searchbox"

                               maxlength="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */

                               echo $helperSearch->getMaxQueryLength(); ?>"

                               role="combobox"

                               aria-haspopup="false"

                               aria-expanded="true"

                               aria-autocomplete="both"

                               autocomplete="off"/>

                        <div id="searchbox_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>

                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml() ?>



                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="actions">

                    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Search')) ?>" class="btn-searchbox">

                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */

                            echo __('Search'); ?></span>

                    </button>

                </div>

            </form>

        </div>



    <?php

    if ($show_popular) { ?>

        <div class="sm-searchbox-popular">

                <div class="sm-searchbox-popular-title"><?php echo __('Top Search:'); ?></div>

                <div class="sm-searchbox-keyword">

                    <?php

                    if (sizeof($this->getTerms()) > 0) { ?>

                        <ul class="sm-searchbox-keyword-list">

                            <?php foreach ($this->getTerms() as $_term) { ?>

                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getSearchUrl($_term); ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_term->getQueryText()); ?></a></li>

                            <?php } ?>



                            <?php if ($show_more) { ?>

                                <li>

                                    <a class="sm-searchbox-more" data-ajaxmore="<?php echo $this->getSearchBoxAjax(); ?>" data-count="<?php echo $limit_popular; ?>"><?php echo $more_text; ?></a>

                                </li>

                            <?php } ?>

                        </ul>

                    <?php } else { ?>

                        <p class="note-msg"><?php echo __(' There are no search terms available.'); ?></p>

                    <?php } ?>

                </div>

            </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ($show_advanced) { ?>

        <div class="sm-searchbox-advanced">

                <a href="<?php echo $this->getSearchBoxAdvanced(); ?>"><?php echo __('Advanced ++'); ?></a>

            </div>

    <?php } ?>



    <?php

    if (!empty($posttext)) { ?>

        <div class="post-text"><?php echo $posttext; ?></div>

    <?php } ?>

    </div>





<script type="text/javascript">

    require([

        'jquery'

    ], function ($) {

        var searchbox = $('#<?php echo $tag_id;?>');

        var firt_load = <?php echo $limit_popular;?>;



        clickMore($('.sm-searchbox-more', searchbox));

        function clickMore(more) {

            more.click(function () {

                var that = $(this);

                var sb_ajaxurl = that.attr('data-ajaxmore');

                var count = that.attr('data-count');

                count = parseInt(count);

                if (firt_load >= count) {

                    count = count + parseInt(firt_load);

                }

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',

                    url: sb_ajaxurl,

                    data: {

                        is_ajax: 1,

                        count_term: count

                    },

                    success: function (data) {

                        $('.sm-searchbox-keyword', searchbox).html(data.htm);

                        clickMore($('a.sm-searchbox-more', searchbox));

                        $('a.sm-searchbox-more', searchbox).attr({

                            'data-count': count + parseInt(firt_load)

                        });

                    },

                    dataType: 'json'

                });

            });

        }



    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

### General Steps

1. Create a new theme (but it looks like you might already have a custom theme)
2. Find which Block the search bar is in
3. Move that Block to a different container using a layout update
4. Find which Block the logo is in
5. Move that Block to a different container using a layout update
6. Create an `_extend.less` file to change the CSS of the search bar and shorten it.

#### 1. Create a New Theme

To create a theme, you should pretty much follow the [official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

#### 2. Find which Block the search bar is in

You can turn on a debugging tool in Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer which will create little red boxes around every template, indicating which block and template the visual elements of the page correspond to.

It turns out the search bar is in:

[image: Search Bar Block]

And the snipped layout file is `vendor/magento-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

#### 3. Move that Block to a different container using a layout update

In your theme, create a folder called `Magento_Search`, with another folder inside called `layout` with a file inside called `default.xml`. *Notice that this parallels the original file that declared this block.*

And use a Magento XML `move` element as shown [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange) to move `top.search` to a different destination.

#### 4 & 5 are just another variation of the process in 2 & 3

#### 6. Create an `_extend.less` file to shorten the search bar

Create an `_extend.less` file in the following directory: `[theme root dir]/web/css/source/_extend.less`

In this file, you can edit the width of the search bar by doing something like:

```
.block.block-search .field.search {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

Don't forget to flush your cache after you're done.

Comment: Jorger, I have update my topic and add content from logo and search engine. I have ready created template in app/design/frontend. Can you please help me how I can do this ?

Comment: You can check it here: https://zabezcen.pl